# Marshaling er Pinvoke Headache

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I cannot seem to pass the right arguments correctly. I get

"Invalid Name Parsing buffer size" error

Lotus notes function in dname.h

```
STATUS LNPUBLIC DNParse(
DWORD  Flags,
const char far *TemplateName,
const char far *InName,
DN_COMPONENTS far *Comp,
WORD  CompSize);
```

structure below

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct DN_COMPONENTS
{   
         public int Flags;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
         public string C;
         public short OLength;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
         public string O;
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
         public string CN;
};
```

c#

Below is what I have tried

```
Status sts = 0;
StringBuilder szServer = new StringBuilder(names.MAXUSERNAME);
string notUsedString = null;
DWORD notUsed = 0;
dname.DN_COMPONENTS xdDC = new DN_COMPONENTS();
sts = nnotesDLL.SECKFMGetUserName(szServer);            
//IntPtr structPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(dname.DN_COMPONENTS)));
//UInt16 num = Convert.ToUInt16(Marshal.SizeOf(structPtr));
//WORD num = Convert.ToUInt16(Marshal.SizeOf(structPtr));
int num = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DN_COMPONENTS));            
IntPtr structPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(num);



sts = nnotesDLL.DNParse(notUsed, notUsedString, szServer, structPtr, (UInt32)num);
this.xdDC = (dname.DN_COMPONENTS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr, typeof(dname.DN_COMPONENTS));
xdDC.CN = Decode(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(structPtr), ushort.MaxValue);

///CN=SomeFirstName SomeLastName/OU=Corp/O=test
```

I am looking for "SomeFirstName SomeLastName"

```
[DllImport("nnotes.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 public unsafe static extern Status DNParse(DWORD notUsed, string notUsedString,     StringBuilder     InName, IntPtr structPtr, UInt32 structPtrSizeOf);
```

I have tried all variations by ref to all, ref to struct, changed to string, int, uint Nothing!!!

Help...

What I am looking for is CN=SomeFirstName SomeLastName/OU=Corp/O=test

Comment: You did not show the native declaration of the struct. Why did you choose Pack=1? Anyway, what you are trying cannot work. You'll need to declare the strings as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to read them out.

Comment: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/9.0/api90ref.nsf/852561bd0045e8e785255b3c005a57bb/24d9907b9ecc4fff8525667700438cc1?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,DN_COMPONENTS

Comment: See the link for structure native

Comment: That struct looks nothing like yours. Why did you pack? Do you understand that you cannot marshal the strings from native to managed using `string`. You have to declare them as `IntPtr`.

Comment: Looks like you just quit adding fields where the web page got screwy.  You do have to add all those other fields beyond OULength as well.  Punishing, surely somebody has done this before.  Call IBM for support.

Answer (score 0):

The problems that I can see:

- You did not declare all the fields in the struct.
- It is unlikely that the struct is packed. Remove the Pack setting.
- You need to declare the pointers in the struct as IntPtr. The marshaller cannot marshal them from native to managed. Declare them as IntPtr and use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi to convert.